# Mix two audio files using ffmpeg on android platform

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am trying to mix two sound files(1. a background music 2.a recording file or a mp3 file) into a single one in android platform.

I setup the Android NDK platform for my project and done with compiling the ffmpeg library and generated the required SO file, now i want to use the amerge function( http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge )in android but i don't know how to implement this command in android,I am having not much idea on Android NDK level coding. So any help, any idea will be appreciated.

Note: If you require more info to answer or any doubt in understanding this question feel free to ask, i'll be happy to share more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with FFMPEG, you can compile a binary 'ffmpeg' and use standard command line by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");`